# 7.x-2.54 Reports as Unsupported

Tags: commerce

Installing the latest Kickstart update, 7.x-2.54, results in the Status report telling me I have an unsupported version of Drupal core. Screencap attached. Notice the installed and recommended versions are the same. I'm also getting emails saying my version of Drupal is unsupported. Does anyone know why this is happening and how to stop it?

[image: Updates image showing contradiction]

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, not sure what could be going on there. Drupal 7.59 is definitely the current version of core, so it may just be some odd bug generating a false negative. Does clearing the caches on the site help at all? If not, I'd just ignore it and / or look in the core issue queue for similar reports.